# How to build a light docker image supporting multiple languages (c, c++, rust, java, go, python, javascript, nodejs, etc..)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm a newbie to docker - and i'm looking to build a docker image which supports multiple language.

What i'm planning to do is to take alpine as a base and install all runtime libs for c++, c, rust, etc... I'm not sure what is the right way to do. I already searched for docker hub but did not find one.

Comment: Runtime libraries for C are already included as Alpine comes with `libc-musl`.

Comment: This will not be a "light" image; the various language interpreters will be rather large.  This also isn't typical Docker practice.  Usually you'll want to package one specific application and only the runtime it needs into an image.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @David, It is not recommended practice in the Docker and it will never create a lightweight image even if you go with alpine.

If you visit the offical docker hub of PHP, nodejs and golang you will be surprised.

- Php approximately **350MB** (Alpine)
- Golang approximately **360MB** (Alpine)
- Nodejs approximately **80MB** (Alpine)

Leave the rest of that you mentioned in the question, for instance, subtract **5MB** in each due to OS alpine size still it above **800MB** which is ultimately become big and big by adding the rest.

Alternatively, you can multi-stage image but again you will have to manage and put conditional statements in your Dockerfile to deal with a command like `npm install` in nodejs and do `composer install` in PHP and bla bla.

You might build an image like this but again it will have to manage like a mess.

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE="go"
FROM golang:alpine as go

FROM node:alpine as node

FROM php:7.0-apache as php

FROM nginx:alpine as nginx

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
ENV BASE_IMAGE=$BASE_IMAGE
```

> Limiting each container to one process is a good [rule of thumb](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

If the rule of thumb for the container to have one process per container then I think it should have an environment for that process only.

[dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)